# android com.android.dialer package is missing on a 4.2 device

Tags: android

I was trying to trigger an ACTION_DIAL intent but then the "queryIntentActivities" didn't find any dialer app installed, however it is supposed to be installed by default or am I wrong ? The device in question is not an official one but a custom one, for professional usage.

Is it possible to get the APK related to this package ? I only found the com.google.android.dialer but it's not the default package

Comment: "the "queryIntentActivities" didn't find any dialer app installed" -- perhaps your `Intent` is not set up correctly. You might consider providing a [mcve]. "however it is supposed to be installed by default or am I wrong ?" -- ask the device manufacturer or whoever installed the custom ROM. For example, tablets may lack dialers. "but it's not the default package" -- there are dozens, if not hundreds, of "dialer" apps pre-installed across the 26,000+ Android device models. There is no single "default package".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm using the default example regarding the use of queryIntentActivities and on my device the list is not empty but it is on the other one. I guess the device manufacturer just removed the dialer package for this specific version since it's present in more recent ones.

Comment: Also bear in mind that `queryIntentActivities()` will not work by default on Android 11 and higher, unless you have a suitable `<queries>` element in the manifest. My guess is that you're not on Android 11 yet, though.